# Stroke on rect in D3 blurry

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am trying to draw a rectangle with a dashed strong in SVG using D3 but when I do the top and bottom dashed lines are blurry. Here is my code:

```
var width = 400,
        height = 400;

var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
        .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate('+height/2+','+width/2+')');

svg.append('rect')
    .attr('width', '185')
    .attr('height', '45')
    .attr('x', -height/2+185/2)
    .attr('y', -width/2+10)
    .attr('fill', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
    .attr('stroke', '#2378ae')
    .attr('stroke-dasharray', '10,5')
    .attr('stroke-linecap', 'butt')
    .attr('stroke-width', '3')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sigscotty/9H9PX/

Here is what it looks like in the browser:

[image]

Any way to get the top and bottom crisp looking like the sides?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[shape-rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#ShapeRenderingProperty) is probably what you want. `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` should do it for your case. Alternatively you could [adjust the y and height](http://cairographics.org/FAQ/#sharp_lines) attributes so that the top and bottom positions are  + 0.5.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the "adjust the attributes in order to centre lines on the centre of a pixel" approach, since it will fall apart if the SVG as a whole is scaled.  And because setting shape-rendering in the CSS is so much easier...

Comment: My issue was that all lines were blurry in IE. So I put a translate(0.5 0.5) on the main SVG and that fixed it. That said, I ABSOLUTELY HATE that the 0.5 shift is a thing. They are scalable vector graphics for gods sake. SCALABLE.

Comment: `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` caused flickering in d3 transitions